# Reducción de imágenes mediante media de submatrices

Tags: c++, imagen, matriz

Estoy intentando reducir una imagen en C++ para crear iconos del tamaño deseado.

La imagen original consiste en una matriz de (**nf**) filas x (**nc**) columnas y se tiene que reducir a (**nf_reduc**) filas x (**nc_reduc**) columnas tal que así:

```
Original (nf = 4, nc = 5):

X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X

Reducida (nf_reduc = 3, nc_reduc = 3):

? ? ?
? ? ?
? ? ?
```

El algoritmo reparte esos píxeles de la imagen original en grupos para que se ajuste al tamaño de la image requerido y para cada uno de esos grupos se hace una media de sus píxeles que posterior mente se le asignaría al pixel de salida de la imagen reducida.

A través de un procedimiento externo a este problema se ha dividido de la siguiente forma.

```
    Original:
-------------
X X | X X | X
X X | X X | X 
-------------
X X | X X | X
-------------
X X | X X | X
```

Cada cubículo es una submatriz a cuyos pixeles se les hará su media y se le asignará a la matriz/imagen pequeña.

```
      |X X|
AVG ( |X X| ) = primer pixel de la imagen reducida.
```

Saco los arrays de los grupos de píxeles:

- array de **grupos de filas** (la primera casilla es la cantidad de filas de la primera submatriz):

  [2, 1, 1]
- array de **grupos de columnas** (la primera casilla es la cantidad de columnas de la primera submatriz):

  [2, 2, 1]

La pregunta es simple pero necesitaba explicar todo lo anterior para que se entienda:

**Cómo puedo hacer para recorrer la matriz original tomando los elementos de cada subgrupo que hay que hacerles la media y asignarlos (matriz reducida)?**

Quizá es demasiado simple pero estoy atascado en este paso. Gracias de antemano.

No es necesario la implementación de la clase Imagen ya que solo necesito conocer como se haría de forma general para estas dos matrices.

Se conocen las funciones de la clase imagen/matriz para original y reducida:

```
leer_pixel(int filas, int columnas);
asignar_pixel(int filas, int columnas);
```

Comment: Pues dependerá de como hayas declarado la *matriz original*, digo yo. Sin ver dicha declaración, será difícil. Adicionalmente, deberías indicar que has intentado y que problemas has tenido en tu intento. Un saludo.

Comment: "*¿Cómo puedo hacer para recorrer la matriz original?*" ¿Qué matriz original? ¡No veo ninguna matriz en tu código! De hecho, no veo código.

Comment: No es necesario saber la implementación de la matriz original, solo necesito saber como se podría hacer de forma general.

Comment: @Albert99, te equivocas. Dependiendo de si la matriz es de memoria dinámica, de memoria estática, un contenedor se hará una cosa u otra, si la matriz está aplanada en una formación, si las dimensiones son estáticas o dinámicas, si se lee desde archivo o desde teclado se actuará de una u otra manera.

Comment: Y que [has intentado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884/cuanto-esfuerzo-se-espera-de-los-usuarios-de-stack-overflow?cb=1)

Comment: @Pablochaches pasar la matriz a un array e intentar leerlo con bucles for y límites en cada grupo pero no ha dado resultado.

Comment: @Albert99 Hombre, pues comparte lo que has intentado. Ya avanzamos desde ahi

Comment: Una pregunta, y cual es el algoritmo para llegar a la version reducida de la matriz? Ya con ese algoritmo tienes que poder hacerte la idea de como recorrerla. O, cuando dices, "*A través de un procedimiento externo a este problema se ha dividido de la siguiente forma.*", te refieres a que siempre es la misma forma?

Comment: @Pablochaches se divide de la siguiente forma:
Si tengo una imagen de 5 filas y quiero transformarla en una de 3 filas pues veo que tendría que tomar los grupos de la siguiente forma (1 fila, 1 fila, 1fila) y vemos que me sobran dos. Esas que sobran se vuelven a repartir equitativamente desde el principio del array de forma que quedarían los grupos como (2filas, 2filas, 1fila)

Comment: Hombre por la cantidad de comentarios, eso que colocaste ya no queda a la vista, y es importante para entender como resolver el problema. Puedes pegarlo arriba?